# How to fix the address regEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help fix regEx. Follow regex fine worked in chrome browser, but it not work in firefox browser. I use lookbehind, which not supported in firefox:

```
/((?<!(д(ом)?|стр(оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)\d+((,?\s*(к(ор(п(ус)?)?)?\.?)\s*\d+)|(\s*[а-я])|(\s*\/\s*\d+))?\s*$)/
```

[LIVE DEMO here.](https://jsfiddle.net/r15ghL79/4/)

```
// this function transform
// Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, 36
// to
// Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, д. 36

function transform(addr) {
  const regEx = /((?<!(д(ом)?|стр(оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)\d+((,?\s*(к(ор(п(ус)?)?)?\.?)\s*\d+)|(\s*[а-я])|(\s*\/\s*\d+))?\s*$)/;
  const endStr = addr.match(regEx);
  let result;
  let ret;

  if(endStr && endStr[0]) {
    result = addr.replace(endStr[0], 'д. ' + endStr[0]);
  } else {
    result = addr;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, 36'));
```

PS:
unfortunately address may consists of several (2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or mode) parts.

I need only regEx approach for this problem solve. Thanks

Comment: What are the rules for adding that `д. `? Will it always be at the end before the last number, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @JamieBarker Last number its home number. it always stand on a last position. But it(home number) may not be at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may convert the negative lookbehind into an optional capturing group:

```
(?<!....) => (....)?
```

So,

```
/((?<!(д(ом)?|стр(оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)\d+((,?\s*(к(ор(п(ус)?)?)?\.?)\s*\d+)|(\s*[а-я])|(\s*\/\s*\d+))?\s*$)/
 V                                        VV   
/((?:д(?:ом)?|стр(?:оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)?\d+((,?\s*(к(ор(п(ус)?)?)?\.?)\s*\d+)|(\s*[а-я])|(\s*\/\s*\d+))?\s*$)/
```

Then, when performing a replacement, check if Group 1 is not undefined, and if not, you know the lookbehind pattern matched and this match should not have occurred, hence, replace with the whole match back in that case. Else, append the text you need.

Here is the updated function:

```
function transform(addr) {
  const regEx = /((?:д(?:ом)?|стр(?:оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)?\d+(?:,?\s*к(?:ор(?:п(?:ус)?)?)?\.?\s*\d+|\s*[а-яё]|\s*\/\s*\d+)?\s*$/;
  return addr.replace(regEx, ($0, $1) => $1 ? $0 : 'д. ' + $0);
}
```

Note I removed all redundant capturing groups or converted to non-capturing (replaced `(...)` with `(?:...)`).

JS demo:

```js
function transform(addr) {
  const regEx = /((?:д(?:ом)?|стр(?:оение)?|\/|-)\.?\s*\d*)?\d+(?:,?\s*к(?:ор(?:п(?:ус)?)?)?\.?\s*\d+|\s*[а-яё]|\s*\/\s*\d+)?\s*$/;
  return addr.replace(regEx, ($0, $1) => $1 ? $0 : 'д. ' + $0);
}

console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, 36'));          // Replacement occurs
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, д. 36'));       // No replacement
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, дом 36'));      // No replacement
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, дом36'));       // No replacement
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, стр36'));       // No replacement
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, стр.36'));      // No replacement
console.log(transform('Татарстан, г. Казань, ул. Баумана, строение.36')); // No replacement
```